# C# Winforms: GroupBox not resizing

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, groupbox

I have two `GroupBoxes` on the left side of one of my `TabControls`, call them GroupBox A (top left), and GroupBox B (bottom left). The GroupBoxes do not resize like I would hope.

**Example:**
When I resize the main form that has the TabControls with my mouse, or maximize it, or move it to a screen with lower resolution, GroupBox B keeps its width / height. This causes GroupBox B to draw over GroupBox A, kind of like a 'always on top' effect.

**Desired:**
Would like both GroupBoxes to resize according to one another / proporitionally and fit the area they are given.

Ideas?

Comment: Check you application CSS

Comment: Thanks Sourabh, but I do not have one, this application is Winform app.

Comment: Ok then set dock property to FILL  and it definitely work

Comment: Cos any control in win form resize when the dock property is set . And it must be set as dock to FILL

Comment: Setting the Dock property to Fill made the group boxes extend to both sides of the form, and covered the DataGridView that is to the right of both GroupBoxes. I tried setting the Dock property to LEFT but had same effect.

Comment: Don't worry set it fill then right click on group box and click on back to front or set to back . You will definitely get what you want .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A tableLayoutPanel can help with this.

1. Add a tableLayoutPanel and size it to fit your needs.
2. Anchor the table to Top, Bottom, Left, and Right
3. Put GroupBoxA into the upper left cell of the table
4. Put GroupBoxB into the lower right cell of the table
5. For both GroupBox size them accordingly and anchor them to all 4 sides.
6. Now they will grow and shrink proportionately with the app.

Additionally you can add more of your controls to the table.  If you need a control to span multiple rows or columns use the RowSpan/ColumnSpan property.

Comment: Still testing that answer, no luck yet. Are you sure you want GroupBox A in upper left cell and GroupBox B in lower right cell? Wouldn't it be GroupBox A in upper left cell and GroupBox B in lower left Cell? Making the tableLayoutPanel with one column in other words?

Comment: It depends on your layout.  If two cells gives you what you want, then you can use one column and then fiddle with the anchoring to get the effect you want.  If you want to make sure that GroupBoxB doesn't overlap the bottom or right of GroupBoxA then you'll need 2 columns.  If you only care about it not passing the bottom, then only one column is needed.

Comment: yeah, just two groupboxes on a tabControl on the left side. One on top of the other. To the right of them is a DataGridView. They all resize well except the GroupBoxes. Still playing with anchoring and such, no luck yet. Best I can get is after putting the two groupBoxes into a single column tableLayoutPanel, one on top of other, anchoring them both to TBLR, the group boxes show only half drawn and are cut off. Very strange. Should I upload screenshots of this?

Comment: You can also add all of your controls to the tableLayoutPanel, not just the groupBoxes.  The controls can span multiple cells of the table to suit your needs.  So do you only have three controls?  Two group boxes and a DataGridView?

Comment: Sorry, been playing with this and not watching this thread. I'll describe the form like a table. 
First row, a group box that goes across the form. 
Second row, I have the tableLayoutPanel, then the DataGridView
3rd row, I have a update progress bar that goes across to two buttons to the bottom right edge of the form. 
I think you're saying I should put everything into the tablePanelLayout. I'll have to work on that this weekend and see what I can fit, move and anchor, etc. 

Any rules of thumb to make this work, such as Docking and Anchoring?

Comment: So from what you've said, this is what I would do.  Put the groupBoxes and DataGridView in the table with a single column, each in a cell and set the dock property of each to fill.  position the progress bar and buttons according to the desired distance from the tabs edges.  The buttons should be anchored to the bottom and right.  The progress bar, anchored to the left, bottom and right if you want it to stretch with resizing.  The table itself should be anchored to all four sides.  Let me know how that turns out.

Comment: Odd, I replied, but don't see it here. Anyway, I've been testing with it most of the weekend, it does appear to be working, I'll be trying the test on the laptop which has the lowest resolution and was the final test today and I'll  update the post with the results.

Comment: Is there a way to make a TLP with 2 columns, and the first column has two rows, and the 2nd column has one? I'd be able to fit my objects much better in that kind of setup now that I'm understanding how it works.

Answer (score 3):

If your GroupBox is inside another control like a tab or something, then do as below:

In my case I had a GroupBox inside a tab and I called the below methods in the `InitializeComponent()` method to force the Groupbox to adjust to the tab size.

```
this.groupBox4.ResumeLayout(false);
this.groupBox4.PerformLayout();
this.tabPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
this.tabPage2.PerformLayout();
```

And If you have multiple GroupBoxes, you need set the anchoring accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, I just had used the split container for both GroupBoxes, anchored the split container at top, bottom, left an right of my main form, and both GroupBoxes too, at top, bottom, left and right of their containers.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off topic from the original question, but my issue was that my MaximumSize field of my Group Box was not set, or was too small so I could not resize the height!

Answer (score 1):

Altought the question is pretty old, someone might still find it useful...
I had the same problem and found a working solution -> instead of changing the width/height of the GroupBox, change its minimum width/height in the Form's resize method

edit: fixed typo

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        groupBox1.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width /2, this.Height);
    }
```